# What would I return in this situation

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, std, shared-ptr

I will post my code then explain my query:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<SEntity> Entity;

//Scene_Ids is an enum
static std::map<Scene_Ids, std::vector<Entity> > m_scene_entities;

std::shared_ptr<SEntity>& SEntityManager::getEntity(const std::string& entity_name)
{
    int counter = 0;

    for (auto iter = m_scene_entities.begin(); iter != m_scene_entities.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if (iter->second[counter]->getId() == entity_name)
            return iter->second[counter];

        counter++;
    }

    //What would I return if the entity couldn't be found?
}
```

The code basically explains it all. I have a method in which if an "entity" is found in the std::vector inside of the map, it will return a reference to the std::shared_ptr type that it is. However, since I'm not returning a pointer, I cannot return nullptr. What could I return in a failure case.

Also, I know that std::shared_ptr is meant for having copies in several different places. For this, do I really need to return a reference or can I just return it by value?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you return a `shared_ptr` to `nullptr`?

Comment: Isn't that the same problem as `std::map::find` vs `std::map::operator[]`?

Comment: @templatetypedef OP's returning a reference.

Comment: @dyp Ah, missed that. Thanks!

Comment: Will you need to modify the std::shared_ptr object itself OR the object that is kept within it? The answer depends on that

Comment: @Zeks Yes, I'm returning a reference to it in order to modify that specific Entity.

Comment: An interesting question then... maybe create an Entity nullvalue; inside the class and return a reference to it?

Comment: Although I like an idea of returning an iterator from the answer below

Comment: @PeterSenyszyn - Your code looks a bit off. You are looking only at the zeroth element of the vector of entities in the zeroth entry in the map, only at the first element of the vector in the first entry in the map, etc. I think you need a doubly-nested loop here. Have the outer loop loop over the m_scene_entities map. (This is what you are doing now). Have the inner loop loop over the vector of entities in that map entry. (This is what you are missing.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Return the iterator rather than the contents of the iterator. That way you can tell whether you reached the end.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on that? I'm a little bit confused on how that would be used.

Comment: Think how `std::map::find` works. It returns an iterator. In your case, you could (for example) return an iterator to the found object and an end iterator to the vector containing the found object.

Comment: you can return an iterator and outside of the function compare it to m_scene_entities.end() to check if there was anything found.

Comment: @Zeks - The problem here is that `m_scene_entities.end()` is the end of the map. Each map entry contains a vector of entities, and he wants to return an element of one of those vectors.

Comment: Yes, I have already noticed that when I tried to write an answer to him. The point is - then your answer won't work because to check if an iterator reached an end you will need to compare it to vec.end() and he does not know which vec to check against...

Comment: Returning a pair of iterators solves that problem, the found iterator and the appropriate end iterator. If not found, return any end iterator, duplicated as a pair.

Comment: This is getting so complex it looks like his actual problem is approaching the problem in the wrong way :)

Answer (score 1):

If it is expected that under normal circumstances `getEntity` will **never** fail to find the entity, then you should `throw` an exception.

If you would expect to fail to find some entites, then you can return a default-constructed `shared_ptr <SEntity>`.  Be sure to check for that on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the return by reference then return an empty shared pointer:

```
std::shared_ptr<SEntity> SEntityManager::getEntity(const std::string& entity_name) {

  for { ... }

  return Entity();

}
```

There's not really a good reason to return the shared pointer by reference. And the shared pointer has a default constructor that's basically the equivalent of `nullptr`. You can check it in the parent function by testing it as a `bool`. E.g.:

```
auto val = getEntity(...);
if (!val) { /* nothing found */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need to split tasks. For any normal operation (changing the values of SEntity parameters) you will just need to either return default constructed std::shared_ptr or found entity. No reference needed.

For *replacing the actual contents of shared_ptr* you can have a function like

```
void SEntityManager::replaceEntity(const std::string& entity_name, Entity* newEntity)
```

and replace the Entity if its found inside the function.

However, your code still is weird - what if, for example, there are multiple entity_name containing Entities in your vectors ?